Federated Learning in ColabPro
I am trying to build a Federating Learning on ColabPro using Flower and pytorch-lightning, but I need to specify an IP & Port number for the server so the clients can communicate with it, also I have to run the server and each client seperately through the multiple terminals, my problem now is I don't know which IP & Port numbers can I use, and how to open multiple terminals at same times on ColabPro.
I tried same model locally and it works.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
